# integration and differentiation with sympy/pyqt python

Tags: python, math, sympy

I'm creating a system which quizes the user on integration and differentiation using python 3. when i display questions they are in a form like:

```
-25*x**(3/5)/3 + 6*x**(4/3) - 5*x**6/3 + x**2/2 - 4*x
```

How could I change it to a form like:

```
-25x^(3/5)/3 + 6x^(4/3) - 5x^6/3 + x^2/2 - 4x
```

Also I want it so when users type in equivalent answers it is still recognised

Comment: For answers, it sounds like you might need a parser that can convert input to proper math notation, then check against your answer. Could you simply have some input to test if their output matches yours?

Comment: Are you just outputting to the console or using this somewhere else? If for example if this is output going to a webpage you would be able to do a bunch of interesting things with the formatting.

Comment: Why not parse the function as a string, replacing circumflexes with double asterisks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple display replacement you could use:

```
def format_math(string):
    return (string.replace("**", "^")).replace("*", "")
```

Then you could use it versus user input to compare their input answer versus yours.

```
 x = format_math("-25*x**(3/5)/3 + 6*x**(4/3) - 5*x**6/3 + x**2/2 - 4*x")
 # -25x^(3/5)/3 + 6x^(4/3) - 5x^6/3 + x^2/2 - 4x
 user_input = format_math(input("Enter your answer: "))
 # If the user enters # -25x^(3/5)/3 + 6x^(4/3) - 5x^6/3 + x^2/2 - 4x or
 # -25*x**(3/5)/3 + 6*x**(4/3) - 5*x**6/3 + x**2/2 - 4*x the program will 
 # recognize both as correct
 if x == user_input:
     return True
```

From the [python docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to use `sympy`, then the following will work:

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x')
sp.init_printing()

y = -25*x**(sp.Integer(3)/sp.Integer(5)
    )/sp.Integer(3) + 6*x**(sp.Integer(4)/sp.Integer(3)
    ) - sp.Integer(5)*x**sp.Integer(6)/sp.Integer(3) + x**sp.Integer(
    2)/sp.Integer(2) - 4*x

y
```

[image: SymPy expression]

Expressions can then be simplified and compared using `sympy`'s tools. If it was preferable to not use `sp.Integer()` explicitly to prevent Python from doing the divisions, one could substitute it into the original expression string using regular expressions before using `sp.sympify()` to convert the string into a SymPy expression.